# How to correctly implement equals(), hashCode() for Tree in Java?

Tags: java, tree, equals, hashcode

I have a tree structure and I need to override the methods equals/hashCode because I use the check of the expected result in the unit tests.

The problem with tree type structures is that they refer to each other recursively. In particular, parents for children and vice versa.

and if all fields are used in the methods equals/hashCode, then there will be a looping. The question is how to correctly override then in order not to violate the contract.

I will give an example of how I implemented it.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book book1 = new Book(1L, "The catcher in the rye");
        Book book2 = new Book(2L, "Rich Dad Poor Dad");

        BookTree bookTree1 = new BookTree(book1);
        BookTree bookTreeChild1 = new BookTree(book2);
        bookTree1.addChild(bookTreeChild1);

        BookTree bookTree2 = new BookTree(book1);
        BookTree bookTreeChild2 = new BookTree(book2);
        bookTree2.addChild(bookTreeChild2);

        if (!bookTree1.equals(bookTree2)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid override equals");
        }
    }
}

class Book {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Book(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (this == object) return true;
        if (object == null || getClass() != object.getClass()) return false;
        Book book = (Book) object;
        return Objects.equals(id, book.id) &&
                Objects.equals(name, book.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name);
    }
}

class Tree<T> {
    private List<Tree<T>> children = new ArrayList<>();
    private Tree<T> parent = null;
    private T data;

    public Tree(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Tree(T data, Tree<T> parent) {
        this.data = data;
        parent.addChild(this);
    }

    public List<Tree<T>> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void addChild(Tree<T> child) {
        child.setParent(this);
        this.children.add(child);
    }

    public void addChild(T data) {
        Tree<T> newChild = new Tree<>(data);
        this.addChild(newChild);
    }

    public void removeChildren() {
        this.children = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addChildren(List<Tree<T>> children) {
        for(Tree<T> t : children) {
            t.setParent(this);
        }
        this.children.addAll(children);
    }

    private void setParent(Tree<T> parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Tree<T> getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public boolean isRoot() {
        return (this.parent == null);
    }

    public boolean isLeaf() {
        return this.children.size() == 0;
    }

    public void removeParent() {
        this.parent = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (this == object) return true;
        if (object == null || getClass() != object.getClass()) return false;
        Tree<?> tree = (Tree<?>) object;
        return Objects.equals(children, tree.children) &&
                Objects.equals(data, tree.data);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(children, data);
    }
}

class BookTree extends Tree<Book> {

    public BookTree(Book data) {
        super(data);
    }

    public BookTree(Book data, Tree<Book> parent) {
        super(data, parent);
    }
}
```

As you can see from my implementation, I use only two fields: "data" and "children". 
Accordingly, my question is whether I implemented the methods equals/hashCode correctly? 
If wrong, then please show how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Accordingly, my question is whether I implemented the methods equals/hashCode correctly?

First of all: "what is correct?" ... one could wonder why a Tree should implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` in the first place. Especially `hashCode()` is tricky: the point of that method is (mainly) so you can store the corresponding object in a HashMap/HashSet. But that raises a big red flag: both these classes do **not** like it, when `hashCode()` returns different values over time. And that is exactly what your code will be doing: every time you change your tree (adding/removing a node), `hashCode()` will give a different result.

So we could have a look at what the standard libs do: and there we find [JTree](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/javax/swing/JTree-source.html) ... which doesn't implement both methods! On the other hand, when we look towards [AbstractSet](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/AbstractSet-source.html) (which is the base class for TreeSet), there we find that both methods are implemented and include the members. So both ways seem to be valid.

Coming back to the question: that really depends how you *want* these two methods to work. Are two trees equal when they have the exact same content (meaning: does the order of children matter)?

Long story short: assuming that you want to ensure that all *data* is equal, and that all *children* are equal, and in the same order, then your implementation seems correct.

And yes, that *restriction* to only check these two attributes makes a lot of sense: when you include the parent link, you immediately get into a recursion that can't be broken.

Finally: you tagged this question with JUnit. This implies that you consider writing tests for your production code. Then these tests should answer your question. Meaning: one approach would be that you sit down and **define** the contract for these two methods. And then you create a number of test cases that **verify** all aspects of these contracts. And then your test cases tell you whether your production code meets your contract.

I think that is the crucial point here: there is no universal rule that tells us if/how to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` for a Tree class. You have to look into your requirements if/how to do that. Then you derive tests from that knowledge, which you then you apply in order to verify if a given implementation meets the requirements/contract.

Comment: This answer highlights some of the fundamental problems with Java's implementation of OO and OO in general. "both these classes do not like it, when `hashCode()` returns different values over time". There's no getting around changes over time in typical OO design... and if a class doesn't like it... that's a big problem. I have recently discovered that JTree doesn't like it when `hashCode` and `equals` are not implemented and ... they are _not_ implemented in `DefaultMutableTreeNode`. "Mutable" implies changes over time. `JTree.getRowForPath` doesn't work without `hashCode()`. So many problems

Comment: Some details on what I'm referring to above...

`JTree` uses `VariableHeightLayoutCache` for a map of `TreePath`s to `TreeStateNode`s. `TreePath.hashCode` delegates to the last node in the tree path, which is a `TreeNode`. Many implementations use `DefaultMutableTreeNode`, which doesn't implement `hashCode` (uses `Object.hashCode`, which varies based on the instance, not the values of the properties in the object or the logical equality of two instances). Therefore, two `TreePath`s with the same logical value will have different results when querying their `JTree`.

Comment: I understand this isn't the OP's question about `hashCode` and `equals` on the tree itself, but I think it's relevant since one would not expect `hashCode` to be necessary here, either. In general, it's a good idea to override `equals` because this is a basic operation one might want to perform and the default implementation is inadequate. `hashCode` must be overridden, too, then to satisfy the Java contract that `hashCode` values are equal if `equals` returns true. So I think the OP is fine to want to implement these, but yes, the OP must define what constitutes equality.

Answer (score 0):

I think @GhostCat's answer where they ask "what is correct?" is crucial. I would like to focus on this part.

The sample given in the OP can be considered correct.

I would name the `Tree` class `TreeNode`, however. I think that's a more appropriate name. Then the question becomes are two `TreeNode`s equal if they have the same data and same children but a different parent? That's the current implementation of the OP. This can be considered correct. If, however, the requirement is that a `TreeNode` also has the same parent, then the entire tree must be equal when comparing two tree nodes. In that case, it doesn't really make sense to ever compare two tree nodes, why not just compare the two trees from the root node? I say this, because there is value in comparing two nodes within the tree and ask the question, "Are these two subtrees equal, regardless of the different parent?" So I believe the OP's code offers more flexibility than requiring that the parent also be equal. In this case the `parent` property is used for convenient navigation and not for identity. You can also imagine a `TreeNode` where there is no `parent` property and only the parent knows of its children. This would make data integrity easier to maintain (because the link is only stored in the parent), but navigation more challenging).

I favor the approach of thinking of `parent` as used for navigation or simply removing the `parent` property from `TreeNode` (or `Tree` as the OP calls the class).